# Close this question that was reposted on MO?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

A good question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3608/what-categorical-mathematical-structures-best-describe-the-space-of-localized) was moved to MO for better viewership(probably a good call). But now I think it should be at least closed, and maybe deleted? Discuss.

Comment: proposal: Edit the question to include the MO link and then close it.

Comment: Modification of Tom's proposal for dealing with duplicates between MO and math.SE. Close the question as a duplicate (of I don't care what). The [community user](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/users/-1) will edit the question to include a link to the other question. Then somebody can edit the question to change the link to the right thing. That way, it looks almost exactly as if the question were properly closed as a duplicate of the question on the other site.

Comment: I must be forgetting how to read, what are you suggesting Anton, for some reason I cannot parse it. :/ (Note, I fully expect that this is my problem, not yours.)

Comment: Why close it, actually?

Comment: In general, see http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/310/vote-to-close-as-exact-duplicate-should-accept-mathoverflow-question-urls and especially the comments there.

Comment: @Isaac, yep that's what I was thinking.

Comment: @BBischof: Sorry for the confusing language. Tom suggested, *"edit the question to include the MO link and then close it."* I was just pointing out that (until Isaac's suggestion is implemented) it works out better if you first close the question and **then** edit it to include the MO link

Comment: @Anton, thanks, I am not sure why I had such difficulty understanding.